# Forum for ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am buidling a new site for an organisation. I am using ASP.NET MVC. The previous site was PHP based and had a PHPBB forum. This forum opened in an IFrame, so no integration.

We want a site with all functionality integrated. I thought, I probably have to write a forum myself. However there are other ASP.NET open source forums out there just like phpbb.

Is there a way to integrate third-party forums cleanly into my site? Or am I better of coding it myself?

Answer (score 2):

Check my answer to this question, for an ASP .NET MVC based forum:

- [Who knows a good free open source forum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255591)

If you want an ASP .NET Webforms forum I can recommend you [YetAnotherForum.NET](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is still in beta stage and not much free options are available on the .NET side of things.

It's actually a very easy task if you already have experience writing MVC app.

Not counting those that haven't got some stable releases out, most free options such as YAF are written to run as a standalone applications on classic ASP.NET webforms framework and will often requires that you use a certain fixed database platform and thus will require work to patch them so they integrate nicely with the MVC framework.

So I suggest you code it up yourself. Especially if you just want an integrated forum that don't need to have as much features as phpbb.

Or better yet, start an open source project!

Comment: How do you suggest I start open-source for an organisation specific site?

Comment: You could tear out the forum and run it as a standalone app. Then make it open source. So other people could use it. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah probably, maybe an idea. But then some up-front thinking needs to go into how to seperate it probably from the rest of the application.

Comment: @IceHeat that's why most oss project are made in 'hobby time' ;-)... It's just a suggestion... would be nice to get access to one myself.

Answer (score 0):

The following post has numerous options: [ASP.NET MVC Forum Software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739388/asp-net-mvc-forum-software)